# Access variable in function which executes after setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set the state in reactjs "sync". The way I do this is with a callback:

```
myFunction(){
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i > 100; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    this.setState({
        someValue: 999
    }, () => {
        //this.arr return undefined
        return this.arr;                
    });
}
```

I am almost sure this is a scoping issue. I thought if it has the arrow function it should work? I tried using "this" and without "this", but it is undefined.

Comment: What is `this.rr`? (maybe a typo?) If you just want to access the array, you can do that with `arr`. What are you trying to achieve by `return`ing from the callback? Can you provide a better description of the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: When myFunction is called I want to update the state variable 'someValue' (this is a react project). As well, I want to then return the array back to the whoever calls 'myFunction()'

Comment: If you really want to return the array after the state was updated, you can either make `myFunction` accept a callback and pass the array to it, or return a promise and resolve it to the array after the state updated. You cannot return the array synchronously since the state is updated asynchronously.

Comment: @user2924127, why do you need to return an array from `myFunction`?

Comment: @FelixKling but is the: () => {
        //this.arr return undefined
        return this.arr;                
    }); already a callback? Shouldn't the returning of the array only happen once 'somevalue' has been set?

Comment: Yes it is a callback and yes, the returning happens after the value was set. But where do you think that function returns the value to? The return value can only be accessed by the caller of the function. But your code doesn't call the callback, it is called somewhere inside React. Hence returning `arr` here is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You are right issue is scoping. this inside arrow function does not refer to arr of function

if you really want to use anonymous function then you can do it like this

```
myFunction(){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i > 100; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    var xyz = function()  {
        //this.arr return undefined
        return this.arr;                
    };
    this.setState({
      someValue: 999
    }, xyz);
}
```

this is a very good article of arrow function.
https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e

Comment: This will produce the exact same outcome as the original code.

Comment: No it won't. In this case this.arr will refer to arr of this function

Comment: *"In this case this.arr will refer to arr of this function"* Which function? It doesn't matter though. That's not how `this` works. `this.arr` inside the callback can never refer to the `arr` variable defined outside.

Answer (score -1):

don't use var for define variables (you can read about scoping with var and let)

just use let in you case problem with var i = 0

Comment: `var` and `let` will produce the same result in this situation. The problem isn't about variable scope here.